# Using table tag to structure a web page decrease referencing quality?

Tags: googlebot, table

I am student in web programing. I use massively `<table> ... </table>` to structure my web page.

My professor once told me it could decrease the referencing quality for my websites, so I ask myself this question :

Why does a `<table>` tag is a bad practice in structuring a webpage instead of using it for basic data dysplaying ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using tables for website structure is an old practice, by some even considered even a bad one, with current technologies you got more options, maybe not ar intuitive as using tables but they come with great advantages. To list a few:

- Your code could be greatly reduced by using  wrappers instead of tables, which could result in smaller size websites and smaller loading times.
- Search engines find easier to crawl a website with less markup, so they can decipher between code and content.
- By using other structural techniques, you will be able to adapt easier to mobile responsive sites, or resizing your website for different screen sizes, which is a great practice in modern website programming.

Here there are some links [1](http://chromaticsites.com/blog/13-reasons-why-css-is-superior-to-tables-in-website-design) [2](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/08/from-table-hell-to-div-hell/) where you can see more advantages altho they could be quite old, I found them very useful.

Answer (score 2):

Its not necessarily bad in my opinion. Using tables is "old school" and in some ways limiting in terms of what you can do with your layout. However, tables are still useful in some cases for cross browser compatibility and designing email templates. Old school sometimes means more stable.

I preferred using div's in combination with CSS because it allows for a ton of layout freedom and responsiveness. Also, you save quite a bit of time when you use a framework such as [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) and etc. Lastly, you code is much shorted and cleaner in most cases.

Comment: I chosen the second answer, but if I could I would chose both of yours. Thank you for those information, I will take a look at Bootstrap soon.